# How can I sort a component in React?

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I have a component I'm importing in a page and I'm creating a sort by option.

I'm using .map for the component. Something like:

```
{data.posts.map((post) => (
        <Box>
          <Heading>{post.title}</Heading>
          <Box>{post.content}</Box>
        </Box>
))}
```

Then I import that component:

```
<Posts data={data} />
```

Now I tried to do something along the lines of using .reverse()

Where I use useState and toggle between ascending and descending then attach that to Posts.

```
<Posts data={data} sortBy={order} />
```

and inside the component:

```
{sortBy === "ascending"
        ? data.posts.map((post) => (
            <Box>
              <Heading>{post.title}</Heading>
              <Box>{post.content}</Box>
            </Box>
          ))
        : data.posts.reverse().map((post) => (
            <Box>
              <Heading>{post.title}</Heading>
              <Box>{post.content}</Box>
            </Box>
          ))}
```

The default is set to ascending and it displays fine and when I sort by descending it works but if I try to sort back to ascending it doesn't do anything. It remains in descending. Only when I click descending again does it go back to normal. So ascending works great for first loading the page, and then I have to use descending to switch between orders.

Now I could have maybe used this and just initially load ascending then use reverse for both ascending and descending but I have a Dark/Light mode button trigger and when clicked it causes the order to trigger as well due to the change of state.

I was hoping to avoid having to make another API call and apply the sorting via the call but is that really the only option?

Comment: The `reverse` function modifies in place (modifies the original list). One option would to be clone then reverse e.g. `[...data.posts].reverse().map()`. Or re-sort the list each time sortBy changes, and simply display the list as is (post-sorting).

Comment: Alternatively, use `.sort()` and pass in a callback sorting the elements how you want.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The reverse function modifies the list in place (it modifies the original list). Because you don't *undo* that reversal, it stays reversed.

One option would to be shallow copy/clone the list and then reverse it:

```
[...data.posts].reverse().map(post => { })
```

Or you could re-sort the list each time `sortBy` changes, and simply display the list as is (post-sorting).